# transitive and intransitive verbs using を/が particle

Tags: transitivity

Was studying Anki when i came across やっと難しい問題が解けった

Instead of using the が particle, would it also be plausible to use the を particle here? I know that transitive sentences normally uses を and intransitive uses が, but how "wrong" (in terms of trying to express my thoughts to others) is it to use を in this case. Would the other party, not be able to decipher what I am trying to say? I know that using the verb　解かす with the を particle would probably be more correct, but I am just curious on whether it is still decipherable to others

Comment: Are you sure it's 解け**っ**た, not 解けた ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

解ける happens to be the potential form of transitive 解く:

> 問題が解ける (present)、問題が解けた (past)
>   ↑ intransitive "solve"
>   問題が(orを)解ける (present)、問題が(orを)解けた (past)
>   ↑ **potential** form of transitive 解く "solve"

So grammatically speaking you can say:

> やっと難しい問題**が**解けた。 *The problem finally got solved / I could finally solve the problem*
>   やっと難しい問題**を**解けた。 *I could finally solve the problem*

---

> I know that using the verb 解かす with the を particle would probably be more correct

No, use 解**く**, not 解かす here:

> 問題を解**く** (present)、問題を解**いた** (past)
>   ↑ transitive "solve"

<sub>You're right that とかす is transitive, but it means "melt" "dissolve" "comb out" etc. (溶かす, 融かす, 解かす, 梳かす etc.) You don't say 問題を解かす to mean "solve a problem".</sub>

So you can say:

> やっと難しい問題**を**解いた。 *I finally solved the problem*

---

> I know that transitive sentences normally uses を and intransitive uses が, but how "wrong" is it to use を... Would the other party, not be able to decipher what I am trying to say?

For example, if you said:

> *パソコン**を**壊れた。
>   *ガソリンの値段**を**上がりました。
>   *お風呂**を**沸いた。

it'd depend on the context but native speakers would usually think that you meant to say:

> パソコン**が**壊れた。 or パソコンを壊**し**た。
>   ガソリンの値段**が**上がりました。
>   お風呂**が**沸いた。 or maybe お風呂を沸**かし**た。

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise it was in its potential form. It is possible to use を and が for potential form of verbs, and i myself might have had heard some natives using を with the potential form. Why does Tae Kim's guide discourages the use of を particle when used with the potential form? Link: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/potential#Potential_forms_do_not_have_direct_objects

Comment: @Newbie そうですね。。 It's probably because using が is more common... I think 「富士山**を**登れた。」「重い荷物**を**持てます。」 are okay too, though it might depend on the context.